# Prove that for a general 3-cycle $\sigma$ one can find a permutation ...

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I need to prove that for a general 3-cycle $\sigma$ one can find a permutation $\tau \in S_4$ such that $\tau \sigma\tau^{-1} = (123)$, and use this to show that 3-cycles in $S_4$ are even. How do i start?

I just need a hint =)

Answer (score 2):

Let $\sigma=(a \, b \, c)$ be a $3$ cycle. Then you are looking at a permutation $\tau$ such that $\tau^{-1}(1 2 3)\tau=(a\, b \, c)$. Now, LHS=$(\tau^{-1}(1)\, \tau^{-1}(2)\, \tau^{-1}(3))$ (Prove this). Then can you determine $\tau$?

Answer (score 0):

As I am just a student, I hope my answer is correct and will helpe you and others.

Let $ \sigma =(a \ b \ c) $ with $a,b,c \in \left \{1,2,...,n  \right \}$.

Since we know that in $S_n$ we have $ \tau (i\ j) \tau^{-1}= (\tau(i) \ \tau(j) )$ and that $(i\ j\ k)=(i \ j)(j\ k)$ we can write:
$$\tau \circ (a\ b\ c) \circ \tau^{-1} = \tau \circ (a\ b) \circ \tau \circ \tau^{-1} \circ (b\ c) \circ \tau^{-1} = (\tau(a)\ \tau(b)) \circ (\tau(b)\ \tau(c))=(\tau(a)\ \tau(b); \tau(c))$$

And because we want $(\tau(a) \ \tau(b)\ \tau(c))=(1\ 2\ 3)$ we just have to ask $\tau(a)=1,\tau(b)=2,\tau(c)=3 $ .

The reason on why this reasonning is not valid for $n<5$ is because of the pigeon hole principle.
You can find a more detail explanation [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4839236/n-geq-5-prove-that-the-3-cycles-of-a-n-are-pairwise-conjuguates-in-a-n/4839251#4839251).